# Server Error in Save Site as Template in SharePoint 2010

Tags: site-template, sharepoint-enterprise

I am getting the following error when saving a site as a template (just this specific site is having this issue - other sites in collection successfully save as template)

> System.InvalidOperationException: Error generating solution files in
>   temporary directory.
>        at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.ExportWebAsSolution()
>        at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.ExportWebToGallery(SPWeb web,
>   String solutionFileName, String title, String description, ExportMode
>   exportMode, Boolean includeContent, String workflowTemplateName,
>   String destinationListUrl)
>        at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.ExportWebToGallery(SPWeb web,
>   String solutionFileName, String title, String description, ExportMode
>   exportMode, Boolean includeContent)
>        at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.SaveAsTemplatePage.BtnSaveAsTemplate_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)
>        at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>        at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
>        at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
>        at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

update
Error reported on the ULS

> 12/05/2011 09:18:02.79    w3wp.exe (0x1EB4)   0x0BA8  SharePoint Foundation   General g3qg    Verbose fullOrRelativeUrl = http://URLmodified.test.com/CDC/SitePages/View test.aspx    1ce906ef-a0b5-4769-8f87-28527757ebd7
>   12/05/2011 09:18:02.79    w3wp.exe (0x1EB4)   0x0BA8  SharePoint Foundation   General g3qh    Verbose Site.Url = http://URLmodified.test.com  1ce906ef-a0b5-4769-8f87-28527757ebd7
>   12/05/2011 09:18:02.79    w3wp.exe (0x1EB4)   0x0BA8  SharePoint Foundation   General g3qj    Verbose url is in site  1ce906ef-a0b5-4769-8f87-28527757ebd7
>   12/05/2011 09:18:02.79    w3wp.exe (0x1EB4)   0x0BA8  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Verbose Leaving Monitored Scope (GetWebPartPageContent#99). Execution Time=14.1515192573358 1ce906ef-a0b5-4769-8f87-28527757ebd7
>   12/05/2011 09:18:02.79    w3wp.exe (0x1EB4)   0x0BA8  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    Verbose **__SQL Query Count=1   1ce906ef-a0b5-4769-8f87-28527757ebd7
>   12/05/2011 09:18:02.79    w3wp.exe (0x1EB4)   0x0BA8  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    Verbose _***Execution Time=14.1515192573358 1ce906ef-a0b5-4769-8f87-28527757ebd7
>   12/05/2011 09:18:02.79    w3wp.exe (0x1EB4)   0x0BA8  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Verbose Entering monitored scope (Add WebParts) 1ce906ef-a0b5-4769-8f87-28527757ebd7
>   12/05/2011 09:18:02.79    w3wp.exe (0x1EB4)   0x0BA8  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Verbose Entering monitored scope (Add WebPart with error)   1ce906ef-a0b5-4769-8f87-28527757ebd7
>   12/05/2011 09:18:02.79    w3wp.exe (0x1EB4)   0x0BA8  SharePoint Foundation   Database    tkeb    Verbose Setting database session for {89d93041-8e32-4fa1-9a97-93204642bdf4}.    1ce906ef-a0b5-4769-8f87-28527757ebd7
>   12/05/2011 09:18:02.79    w3wp.exe (0x1EB4)   0x0BA8  SharePoint Foundation   Database    tzku    Verbose ConnectionString: 'Data Source=SampleDBServer;Initial Catalog=SampleDB;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Asynchronous Processing=False;Connect Timeout=15'    ConnectionState: Closed ConnectionTimeout: 15 1ce906ef-a0b5-4769-8f87-28527757ebd7
>   12/05/2011 09:18:02.79    w3wp.exe (0x1EB4)   0x0BA8  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Verbose Leaving Monitored Scope (PSM BSO). Execution Time=7.48754380794207  1ce906ef-a0b5-4769-8f87-28527757ebd7
>   12/05/2011 09:18:02.79    w3wp.exe (0x1EB4)   0x0BA8  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    Verbose* _SQL Query Count=1   1ce906ef-a0b5-4769-8f87-28527757ebd7
>   12/05/2011 09:18:02.79    w3wp.exe (0x1EB4)   0x0BA8  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    Verbose _*SPRequest Objects=0 1ce906ef-a0b5-4769-8f87-28527757ebd7
>   12/05/2011 09:18:02.79    w3wp.exe (0x1EB4)   0x0BA8  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    Verbose* _Execution Time=7.48754380794207 1ce906ef-a0b5-4769-8f87-28527757ebd7
>   12/05/2011 09:18:02.79    w3wp.exe (0x1EB4)   0x0BA8  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Verbose Entering monitored scope (Add WebPart with error)   1ce906ef-a0b5-4769-8f87-28527757ebd7
>   12/05/2011 09:18:02.79    w3wp.exe (0x1EB4)   0x0BA8  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Verbose Leaving Monitored Scope (PSM BSO (1)). Execution Time=3.46608297982006  1ce906ef-a0b5-4769-8f87-28527757ebd7
>   12/05/2011 09:18:02.79    w3wp.exe (0x1EB4)   0x0BA8  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    Verbose _*SQL Query Count=0   1ce906ef-a0b5-4769-8f87-28527757ebd7
>   12/05/2011 09:18:02.79    w3wp.exe (0x1EB4)   0x0BA8  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    Verbose* _SPRequest Objects=0 1ce906ef-a0b5-4769-8f87-28527757ebd7
>   12/05/2011 09:18:02.79    w3wp.exe (0x1EB4)   0x0BA8  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    Verbose _*Execution Time=3.46608297982006 1ce906ef-a0b5-4769-8f87-28527757ebd7
>   12/05/2011 09:18:02.79    w3wp.exe (0x1EB4)   0x0BA8  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Verbose Leaving Monitored Scope (Add WebParts#99). Execution Time=11.1882934842277  1ce906ef-a0b5-4769-8f87-28527757ebd7
>   12/05/2011 09:18:02.79    w3wp.exe (0x1EB4)   0x0BA8  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nass    Verbose _*__Execution Time=11.1882934842277 1ce906ef-a0b5-4769-8f87-28527757ebd7
>   12/05/2011 09:18:02.79    w3wp.exe (0x1EB4)   0x0BA8  SharePoint Foundation   General narq    Verbose Releasing SPRequest with allocation Id {B62DDECF-8CC1-4312-A3C0-820918E91563}   1ce906ef-a0b5-4769-8f87-28527757ebd7
>   12/05/2011 09:18:02.80    w3wp.exe (0x1EB4)   0x0BA8  SharePoint Foundation   General c42u    Monitorable SPSolutionExporter: System.Xml.XmlException: An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 1, position 2925.     at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)     at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseEntityName()     at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseEntityReference()     at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()     at System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadString()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.get_DataFields()     at T_DataFormWebPart_DataFields_65.GetProperty(Object )     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizableAttribute.GetPersonalizablePropertyValues(Control control, PersonalizationScope scope, Boolean excludeSensitive)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartManager.ExportWebPart(WebPart webPart, XmlWriter writer)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.ExportWebPartInternal(WebPart webPart, XmlWriter writer)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPLimitedWebPartManager.ExportWebPart(WebPart webPart, XmlWriter writer)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.GetFilesInFolderTree(SPFolder folder, SortedList`2 filesInFolder, List`1 webViews)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.GetFilesInFolderTree(SPFolder folder, SortedList`2 filesInFolder, List`1 webViews)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.GetFilesInWeb(String workflowTemplateName)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.GenerateSolutionFiles()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.ExportWebAsSolution() 1ce906ef-a0b5-4769-8f87-28527757ebd7
>   12/05/2011 09:18:02.80    w3wp.exe (0x1EB4)   0x0BA8  SharePoint Foundation   General 8hc6    Verbose Deleting temporary directory 'C:\Users\systemaccount\AppData\Local\Temp\SPSolutionExporter-68ff1eb4-e5ec-4475-b16b-4534211d86cf' and its contents during execution of the Dispose method.   1ce906ef-a0b5-4769-8f87-28527757ebd7

Comment: it is not a permission issue.

Comment: Saving with or without content?

Comment: have not tried without content, will keep updated.

Comment: What features are activated within the site?

Comment: Is this a migrated site from SP2007?

Comment: no, it is created on SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Suspecting a webpart issue on one of the page..any help?

Comment: Is there any DataForm webpart in the site which is doing large XSL transformation?

Comment: have removed the Dataform webparts from the "view test.aspx" and it solves the issue...but how does it caused the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the solution in this [TechNet post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/sharepoint2010setup/thread/49f394ee-aa31-4273-b4cb-2b15b424f75d) ?

Also try giving the APP Pool account access to the c:\windows\temp directory.

Comment: Is there any DataForm webpart in the site which is doing large XSL transformation?

Comment: Nice to hear that... I believe your farm has been recently upgraded to SP1 and this might be causing the issue. This is a known issue. Check this post where the third solution might permanently remove your problem. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2639184

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint does many things while saving the site as template; its a long and complex operation. As Deepu suggested, check the access to the temp directory. But you already same operation for other web is working fine (assuming you are trying to save from same machine and save to same directory), so that possibility can be eliminated.

In almost all situations an actual exception message would be logged in ULS logs before InvalidOperationException is thrown.

I suggest you to go to Diagnostic Logging in central admin and enable Verbose trace logging for "SharePoint Foundation -> General" and then watch (I recommend using [ULS Viewer Tool](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer)) what's going on after you try to save as template and before the error appears.